# Qt Creator toolbar doesn't appear

Tags: qt-creator, toolbar, gnome

I can't see the `file`, `edit`, `Build`, `Debug`, `Tools`, `Window` and `Help` buttons in Qt's IDE, and I dont know why.
Maybe there is a key combination like `ctrl + (a letter or number)` to show it, or maybe a problem with the installation.

Specs/other:

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

GNOME Shell 3.10.4

This is how my IDE looks like, as you see, there is no toolbar.

[image: There is no toolbar!]

What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with Ubuntu's quirky menus.  Try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/449250/how-to-get-enable-the-new-locally-integrated-menus-lim-inside-of-the-windows-t

Comment: I'm having the same issue but in XFCE (no titlebar integration apparently)

Comment: Can you please mark my answer as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am using Gnome3 as my window manager as well and This workaround worked for me

sudo apt-get remove appmenu-qt5

Souce : [Link to bug report with the workaround](http://osdir.com/ml/ubuntu-bugs/2014-05/msg00577.html)

Do let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 3):

If you use KDE.
Try configure KDE. In menu: System Settings > Application Style > Window Decorations > Buttons add Application menu to Title bar.
After it, in Qt Creator must appear button with File, Edit, Build.. menu.

Comment: Then you have may have to left or right click on the 3-bar menu for it to work the first time.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 16.04, I used

```
export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=
```

and restarted Qt Creator.

Comment: this solution worked for me. platform : ubuntu 16.04, using Qt 5.8